# AJAX with Selectbox Plugins (Select2, Chosen, Selectize)

Tags: php, ajax, wpdb, select

I have been searching all over the internet for tutorials on implementing AJAX actions from jQuery selectbox plugins such as [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) , Selectize and Chosen. (these plugins look better than the inbuilt jquery ui)

Unfortunatley I cannot find any tutorials specific for wordpress use.

Using one of the tutorials i found on the internet, I adapted it as much as I could to use in wordpress, but unfortunatley I have encountered a **empty Bindvalue()** error.

My HTML document contains the following

```
<label>Option Value :</label>
<input class="input" id="selectbox-v" type="hidden" name="optionvalue" data-placeholder="Choose An Option.." />


<Script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#selectbox-v').select2({
minimumInputLength: 2,
ajax: {
  url: "<?php  get_template_directory()?>/lib/options.php",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: function (term, page) {
    return {
      q: term
    };
  },
  results: function (data, page) {
    return { results: data };
  }
}
});
});

</script>
```

My options.php document contains the following.

```
<?php global $wpdb;

// i have set the limit to 40 to speed up results
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT location_id,location_name FROM $wpdb->locations WHERE location_name LIKE :term ORDER BY option ASC LIMIT 0,40");

// bind the value for security with the wildcard % attached.
$result->bindvalue(':term','%'.$_GET["q"].'%',PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->execute();

// make sure there are some results else a null query will be returned
if($result->rowcount() != 0) {
while($row = $result-&gt;fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $answer[] = array("id"=>$row['location_id'],"text"=>$row['location_id']."  ".$row['location_name']);
    // the text I want to show is in the form of option id - option
 }
} else {
// 0 results send a message back to say so.
 $answer[] = array("id"=>"0","text"=>"No Results Found..");
}

// finally encode the answer to json and send back the result.
echo json_encode($answer);
?>
```

My question:

**Can some please advise me on what I have done incorrectly please?**

PS.trying not to be lazy I did research a bit more before i came here but I did not include my findings in main question because it created more problems. My first assumption was that i used "$wpdb->get_results" instead of "$wpdb->prepare", but changing that brought an additional error that I am missing extra variable arguments.I couldnt find any clarification on how to use "prepare" when my variable is ":term" and not '$id' (which is in most examples).

Comment: you can start by reading [AJAX in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) to learn how to correctly use AJAX in WordPress.

Comment: And please file an [edit] for additional info instead of using comments.